# How can i printpreview multiple excel sheets, with the names of the sheets located in a range?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vba7, print-preview

Good day. I was trying to print preview multiple sheets using an array. I was trying to set an array to a range and using the print preview function that way. Unfortunately it did not work.

The thing i used below:

```
Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin Sheet").Range("A1:A2")

'A1 is "Sheet 1" and A2 is "Sheet 2"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(MyArray)).PrintPreview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Print Preview Multiple Sheets

**Column**

- You need to pass a 1D array without the use of the `Array` function. You can use the late-bound version of the `Transpose` worksheet function to convert the 2D array to a 1D array using the following:

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Dim MyArray As Variant: MyArray = Application _
      .Transpose(wb.Sheets("Admin Sheet").Range("A1:A2").Value)
  wb.Sheets(MyArray).PrintPreview
  ```

  Here `MyArray` holds a 1D one-based array.

**Row**

- If you have the sheet names in a row (e.g. `A1:B1`), you need to wrap the right side of the `MyArray = ...` expression in yet another `Application.Transpose()`:

  ```
  MyArray = Application.Transpose(Application. _
      .Transpose(wb.Sheets("Admin Sheet").Range("A1:B1").Value))
  ```

  Here `MyArray` holds a 1D one-based array.

**Arrays**

- `MyArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin Sheet").Range("A1:A2").Value` returns a 2D one-based (single-column) array held by the `MyArray` variable. You can prove it with the following:

  ```
  Debug.Print LBound(MyArray, 1), UBound(MyArray, 1), _
       LBound(MyArray, 2), UBound(MyArray, 2)
  Dim r As Long
  For r = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 1)
      Debug.Print MyArray(r, 1) ' !!!
  Next r
  ```
- `MyArray = Application.Transpose(wb.Sheets("Admin Sheet").Range("A1:A2").Value)` will return a 1D one-based array held by the `MyArray` variable. You can prove it with the following:

  ```
  Dim n As Long
  For n = 1 To UBound(MyArray) ' or UBound(MyArray, 1)
      Debug.Print MyArray(n) ' !!!
  Next n
  ```
- `Dim Jag As Variant: Jag = Array(MyArray)` returns the 1D `MyArray` in the first and only element of another 1D (usually) zero-based array held by the `Jag` variable. This structure is called a jagged array or an array of arrays. You can prove it using the following:

  ```
   Debug.Print LBound(Jag), UBound(Jag)
   Dim j As Long
   For j = LBound(Jag) To UBound(Jag)
        For n = LBound(Jag(j)) To UBound(Jag(j)) ' !!!
            Debug.Print j, n, Jag(j)(n) ' !!!
        Next r
   Next j
  ```